# Mapping <C-l> doesn't work in Lexplore

Tags: vim

In my .vimrc I have remaps to allow easy moving between windows:

```
noremap <c-l> <c-k>l
```

This works fine unless I'm inside a Lexplore window, in which case `<c-l>` doesn't work, but `<c-k>l` *does*.

Why might this be happening? Is `<c-l>` mapped to something else in netrw?